# Proving unitary inequivalence

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Concerning a finite dimensional vector space, we can determine whether two matrices are unitarily equivalent or not by depending on some similarity invariants or Specht's theorem. If we consider an infinite dimensional Hilbert(Banach?) space, what can we use?

I've heard that the position operator and the momentum operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ are unitarily equivalent by the Fourier transformation. However, the way it's shown doesn't seem to be generalizable. For example, how can we classify unitary equivalence classes of multiplication operators? As densely defined operators on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, $Q_1$ with $Q_1f=xf$ and $Q_2$ with $Q_2f=x^2f$ are unitarily equivalent?

Comment: The unitary equivalent classification of normal operators is given by the spectral theorem.

Comment: I'm a novice at functional analysis.. let me ask a dumb question. I've read the statement of the spectral theorem on unitary equivalence, but there is no mention about the uniqueness. Can we consider it unique in some sense?

Comment: The unitarily equivalent model (unique in a sense) of an arbitary normal operator can be taken in the form of the operator of multiplication by the independent variable on an $L^2$-space for the case of `multiplicity one'. For higher multiplicities one should consider direct sums.

Comment: In your example $Q_2$ splits into the direct sum of its restrictions to $L^2(\mathbb R_+)$ and $L^2(\mathbb R_-)$, which are unitarily equivalent one to another. This can be viewed as an example of multiplicity two (after identification of the subspaces by $x\to -x$).

Comment: Every normal operator on a separable Hilbert space is unitarily equivalent to multilpication by $z$ on $L^2(\mu_1)\oplus L^2(\mu_2)\oplus\dots$ (the sum may be finite or infinite), where each measure $\mu_i$ is unique up to a nonzero weight, and $\mu_{n+1}\le \mu_n$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It sounds very interesting.. I need to study functional analysis from the beginning.

Comment: The elements of the Spectral Theorem are unique. If $A$ is a densely-defined selfadjoint operator, then there exists a unique representation $A=\int \lambda dE(\lambda)$, where $E$ is a Borel orthogonal projection-valued measure satisfying $E(\mathbb{R})=I$, $E(\emptyset) = 0$, $E(S)E(T)=E(S\cap T)$.